# JSON Formatting the ouput of $option value for Drop down select?

Tags: php, json, forms, joomla, chronoforms

This is a newbie question... I have a form in Joomla 3.3 and chronoforms v5 latest... When the form loads the database populates my first select input with "interview dates" from my DB.... works great, once you select the date, the second select input populates with available time slots.... the problem here is the way the DB is output in the array is

Data->
    time->7:00am,7:15am,9:30am

Right now when the 2nd select loads it's showing up like this 7:00am,7:15am,9:30am....
I want to be able to make them individual values not all one value...
This is the code I am currently using for the "time" options for the second select input...

```
    <?php
    $options = array();
    if ( !$form->data['Data'] || count($form->data['Data']) < 1 ) {
      // no result was found
      $options[] = 'Please select a category';
    } else {
      foreach ( $form->data['Data'] as $d ) {
        $options[$d['interviewdate']] = ($d['time']);
      }
    }
    echo json_encode ($options);
    ?>
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The structure that is needed to create an options list is like this:

```
[0] => array ('text' => 'aaa', 'value' => 'xxx'),
[1] => array ( . . .
```

And your data appears to be be in a nested array like $form->data['Data']['time'] ?

In this case the text and value can probably be the same so the code would be something like this:

```
<?php
$options = array();
if ( !$form->data['Data']['time'] ) {
  // no result was found
  $options[] = array('text' => 'Please select a category', 'value' => '');
} else {
  $data = explode(',', $form->data['Data']['time']);
  foreach ( $data as $d ) {
    $options[] = array('text' => $d['time'], 'value' => $d['time']);
  }
}
echo json_encode($options);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken your `$d['time']` holds values like  '7:00am,7:15am,9:30am'. And if this is the case then you can just use `explode(',', $d['time'])` which will give you array of times instead of string.

```
$options = array();
$form = new stdClass();
$form->data['Data'] = array(
    array(
        'interviewdate' => 'date', 'time' => '7:02am,7:25am,9:40am'
    ),
    array(
        'interviewdate' => 'date2', 'time' => '7:05am,7:35am,19:40am'
    )
);
if ( !$form->data['Data'] || count($form->data['Data']) < 1 ) {
    // no result was found
    $options[] = 'Please select a category';
} else {
    foreach ( $form->data['Data'] as $d ) {
       foreach(explode(',', $d['time']) as $time){
          $options[] = array($d['interviewdate'] => $time);
       }
    }
}
echo json_encode ($options);
```

Comment: can you provide structure that you are looking to get? cause by using explode you will get `{"somedate":["7:00am","7:15am","9:30am"],"anotherdate":["7:02am","7:25am","9:40am"]}` and in your example you were getting something like this `{"somedate":"7:00am,7:15am,9:30am","anotherdate":"7:02am,7:25am,9:40am"}` I need to understand what format you are trying to achieve

Comment: Array should look something like this:
time->
[0]->9:00am
[1]->9:15am
[2]->10:00am

Instead of this
time->9:00am,9:15am,10:00am

Comment: This is what I currently get in my array

Array
(
    [chronoform] => demo-dynamic-dropdown
    [Data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [created] => 2014-12-18 17:08:15
                    [department] => Banker
                    [interviewer] => Bob
                    [interviewdate] => 12/31/2014
                    [time] => 9:00 AM,9:15 AM,9:20 AM,10:00 AM,4:00 PM,4:15 PM
                )

        )

)

Comment: interview date is "Key" time is "Value"
12/30/2014 = 9:00am
12/30/2014 = 9:15am
12/30/2014 = 10:00am

Comment: with this `foreach ( $form->data['Data'] as $d ) {
        $options[$d['interviewdate']] = explode(',' , $d['time']);
    }` you will achieve `"anotherdate":["7:02am","7:25am","9:40‌​am"]` or you need something like `[{'12/30/2014':'7:02am'}, {'12/30/2014': '7:05am'}]` ?

Comment: Yes like that [{'12/30/2014':'7:02am'}, {'12/30/2014': '7:05am'}]

Comment: so close!!! the drop down displayed [object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object] when I removed the "[]" from the $options it gave me one item in the dropdown, it was the last one from the string.

Comment: how are you displaying it in javascript then?

Comment: good question, it in a chronoforms extension... I will ask the developer